# Query for only one string

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, ormlite

I recently switched from raw SQLite to ORMLite now i have a table from object called user where max rows is always 1 ( always only 1 user), how i can query with ORMLite for just one string or integer in this table like user id or hash or simmilar?

in the old way i done it like this:

```
public int getCode() {
    int result = -1;
    if (db != null) {
        String rawQuery = "SELECT code FROM settings;";
        Cursor crs = db.rawQuery(rawQuery, null);
        if (crs != null && crs.getCount() > 0 && crs.moveToNext()) {
            result = crs.getInt(crs.getColumnIndex("code"));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

So how should this look like with ORMLite?

Comment: ORMLite returns a full Object instance for each Table record. That object will have *all* its properties set. If you need only one single property, you may use native SQLite queries directly on database.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this example taken from [ORMLite documentation](http://ormlite.com/docs/query-builder):

```
// get our query builder from the DAO
QueryBuilder<Account, String> queryBuilder = accountDao.queryBuilder();
// the 'password' field must be equal to "qwerty"
queryBuilder.where().eq(Account.PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME, "qwerty");
// query for all accounts that have "qwerty" as a password
List<Account> accountList = queryBuilder.query();
```

Comment: +1 Actually there is a `query()` method on the `QueryBuilder` so you can do: `List<Account> accountList = queryBuilder.query();`.  I'll update the docs.

Comment: @Gray Thanks. Let me know whenever you update doc or update this answer with updated details so it could help others.

Comment: I've updated the question @Paresh.  The docs will be updated in the next release.